# pandas importing float values and returning object values how to prevent this?

Tags: python, pandas

i would like to keep the formatation data type of excel when i import on the pandas, but when in the case os screenshot i'am trying to import in my csv the header area venda m2 is numeric but when i import to the pandas it's became a object.

[image: print of excel as a numeric value]

[image: print of my code showing a object value]

Code of the imports

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\LucasSilvaDantasAbra\\Desktop\\teste\\base_nova_040420224.csv', delimiter  = ';')
df.columns
```

Code to show all the colums

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

Data frame

```
dfbase = df
```

Showing types

```
dfbase.dtypes
```

Comment: Well, the obvious step is to take a look at what `dfbase['venda...']` looks like after loading. It might be loading with the thousands mark. If that's the case, pass `thousands=','` to `read_excel`

Comment: passing thousands=',' worked ty

Answer (score -1):

Pandas Data Frame is confused with the commas "," You need to replace then by dots "."